# Concatenating text files by timestamp on the file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to achieve the below in a windows batch file.

I have multiple text files in a folder. I want to create a new text file with all the data in the text files added based on the timestamp on the files (from old to new)

for example I have the following files

163570-23.txt (lets say date modified is sep 13 9:15 am)
10we362s4.txt (date modified is Sep 12 8:56 pm)
w93l-2367.txt (date modified is Sep 13 1:42 pm)

I want to copy data in the above files to a combined file (ex: combine.txt) in the following order.

10we362s4.txt
163570-23.txt
w93l-2367.txt

I dont know how to handle the above. Any help is appreciated and advance thanks for your time.

-Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
del combine.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /OD *.txt') do type "%%i" >> combine.txt
```

How it works:

- del combine.txt

  - We don't want to add the text to a combine.txt file previously generated
- dir /b /OD *.txt

  - Get a list of the .txt files currently in the folder (in date order)
- for /F "tokens=*" %%i (...) do ...

  - For the list of files just generated, run the following command for each item.
- type %%i >> combine.all

  - for each item, get the text of the files specified and append it to combine.txt

Comment: Andy, It worked perfectly. I have another question. I have a folder called backup and it has multiple sub folders underneath it. I want to delete the backup text files in the backup folder(including its subfolders)which are older than 30 days from today. can you please help me with it...thanks again :)

Comment: Probably best to ask a new question & not muddy the waters here.

Answer (score 2):

try someting like
`for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir c:\temp\*.txt /b /od') do type "%%a">>concat.txt`

Comment: Kayasax - Thanks for your inputs. is there a way I can add some points to your reply?